# Having trouble with with if statements being accessed in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm writing a test program that's a math game. I'm working on displaying if the user answers a question correctly that it displays 'correct' (in the shell for now), but it never displays correctly even if all the 10 questions are answered correctly. I have tried multiple things such as changing variables back and forth, which has not achieved anything, and added many print statements to see if the if statement was being accessed, which showed only one thing that was not being accessed.

```
    def addition_frame_fun (self): #Creates the frame where students will be answering addition questions with the labels and entry box.
 
        
        self.add_ans_entry=Entry (self.add_frame)
        self.add_ans_entry.grid (row=3,column=5,padx=5)

        next_btn=Button (self.add_frame,text="Next Question",command=self.generate_add_question)
        next_btn.grid (row=12,column=5,sticky=SE)

    def generate_add_question (self):
        
        self.count+=1

        if self.count <11:

            self.num1=random.randint (1,10)
            self.num2=random.randint (1,10)

            self.num1_str =str (self.num1)
            self.num2_str=str (self.num2)

            self.total= str(self.num1+self.num2)

    
    def check_ans (self):
        
        if self.count > 0:

            self.user_add_ans = str (self.add_ans_entry.get () )

           
        if self.user_add_ans == self.total: 
            
            print (self.total)
            print (self.user_add_ans)
            
            print("correct")
            self.score+=1
```

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. There seems to be a lot of code that isn't necessary to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @bryan job done, thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting `self.total` into a string ,it would be better to convert `self.user_add_ans` into `float` then do the comparison .

Comment: Tried doing that but I get a value error now.

Comment: @VikashPatel does the entry contain a text or something before you assign the value  , because this error will occur if you try to convert a text into a float (for exemple `float('cat')` then python will raise an error) you could check the following link :[https://cs.carleton.edu/cs_comps/1213/pylearn/final_results/encyclopedia/valueError.html#:~:text=To%20encounter%20a%20ValueError%20in,it%20in%20a%20fish%20tank.&text=ValueError%3A%20int()%20cannot%20convert%20'dog'%20into%20an%20integer.]